# SQL QUERY giving me desired output, but taking long time to load the output. how can i optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have three tables, users(which includes user details), territory_categories(which has different territory names and their ids), user_territory(a junction table between the two)

**I want to filter users based on selected territory from the list.**

**query for that is** --

```
SELECT u.id,account_id_fk,first_name,last_name,email_address,password,mobile_number,gender,user_accuracy,check_in_radius,report_to,role,allow_timeout,
  active,last_logged_on,last_known_location_time,last_known_location,u.created_on,u.created_by,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u2.id) FROM fieldsense.users u2 
INNER JOIN  user_territory t1 ON u2.id=t1.user_id_fk 
INNER JOIN territory_categories c on c.id=t1.teritory_id 
**WHERE c.category_name LIKE** "Gujarat"  AND(u2.account_id_fk=1 AND u2.role!=0) ) AS usersCount, 
IFNULL(a.id,0) attendanceId,IFNULL(a.punch_date,'1111-11-11') punchInDate,IFNULL(a.punch_in,0) punchIntime,IFNULL(a.punch_out_date,'1111-11-11') punchOutDate, IFNULL(a.punch_out,0) punchOutTime 
FROM fieldsense.users as u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendances as a ON u.id=a.user_id_fk AND a.id=(select max(id) from  attendances att where att.user_id_fk=u.id) 
INNER JOIN  user_territory t1 ON u.id=t1.user_id_fk 
INNER JOIN territory_categories c on c.id=t1.teritory_id 
**WHERE c.category_name LIKE "Gujarat"**  
GROUP BY u.id  **limit 10**
```

OUTPUT :

```
usersCount: 136
        attendanceId: 0
        punchInDate: 1111-11-11
        punchIntime: 0
        punchOutDate: 1111-11-11
        punchOutTime: 0
    10 rows in set (2.06 sec)
```

And without where clause when it loads it takes almost 1 minute to display the data

OUTPUT without where clause :

```
usersCount: 144
        attendanceId: 0
        punchInDate: 1111-11-11
        punchIntime: 0
        punchOutDate: 1111-11-11
        punchOutTime: 0
    10 rows in set (54.45 sec)
```

I am getting the desired output, but **query is taking almost 1 minute to load**, which i want to optimize. how can i do this ?

Comment: This isn't a Java question... and please for the love of everything you hold dear, *format your code*.

Comment: formatted. please provide good solution to this. need its solution urgently

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I just narrowed down your inner join on table `user_territory`, so it will not join whole `user_territory` table but will only join distinct user_ids in it. Hope it reduces the performance time,

```
SELECT u.id,
 account_id_fk,
 first_name,
 last_name,
 email_address,
 PASSWORD,
 mobile_number,
 gender,
 user_accuracy,
 check_in_radius,
 report_to,
 role,
 allow_timeout,
 active,
 last_logged_on,
 last_known_location_time,
 last_known_location,
 u.created_on,
 u.created_by,
 (
    SELECT
        COUNT(u2.id)
    FROM
        fieldsense.users u2
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id_fk as id, territory_id FROM user_territory ) t1 ON u2.id = t1.id
    INNER JOIN territory_categories c ON c.id = t1.teritory_id 
    WHERE
        c.category_name LIKE "Gujarat"
    AND (
        u2.account_id_fk = 1
        AND u2.role != 0
    )
) AS usersCount,
 IFNULL(a.id, 0) attendanceId,
 IFNULL(a.punch_date, '1111-11-11') punchInDate,
 IFNULL(a.punch_in, 0) punchIntime,
 IFNULL(
    a.punch_out_date,
    '1111-11-11'
) punchOutDate,
 IFNULL(a.punch_out, 0) punchOutTime
FROM
    fieldsense.users AS u
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendances AS a ON u.id = a.user_id_fk
AND a.id = (
    SELECT
        max(id)
    FROM
        attendances att
    WHERE
        att.user_id_fk = u.id
)
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id_fk as id, territory_id FROM user_territory ) t1 ON u2.id = t1.id
INNER JOIN territory_categories c ON c.id = t1.teritory_id 
WHERE
    c.category_name LIKE "Gujarat" 
GROUP BY
    u.id 
LIMIT 10
```